# Pretty-printing with gdb/Python, and type conversion

Tags: c++, gdb, pretty-print

I have a C++ object that contains some binary representation of some data (think of a binary JSON format). I would like to pretty print it using gdb.

```
class Info {
 private:
  unsigned char* p_

 ...
}
```

As a consequence, I would like to display the next 8 bytes pointed to by the pointer `p_` as a `double` or the next 4 bytes as an `int`. How can I do that? I am looking on what to do in the following Python code whew I placed the `...`.

```
def children(self):
    pointer = self.val['p_']
    ...
    yield string, value
```

Comment: cast, dereference...

Comment: @Karoly: I just don't know how to do that in Python